# Approximate arcsinc

Tags: code-golf, math

The goal is simple: Output a nonzero real solution `x` to the equation `sin(x) = -mx`, given input `m`, in the fewest number of bytes.

Specifications:

- Your answer must be correct to 3 significant figures.
- You may output any real solution other than the trivial solution `x=0`. You can assume `m` is such that at least one solution exists. You may also assume `m!=0`.

An obviously suboptimal python solution using *gradient descent*:

```
from math import *
from random import *
a=x=0.001
m = 5.
def dE(x):return 2*(sin(x)+m*x+1)*(cos(x)+m)
for i in xrange(1000): x-=dE(x)*a
print x
```

Test cases

```
-0.25 -> ±2.4746
-0.1  -> ±2.8523 or ±7.0682 or ±8.4232
 0.2  -> ±4.1046 or ±4.9063
```

Comment: The best approach here is to print a fixed value, though you should specify how many decimal places are required. I'd suggest including an input parameter, like `a` to solve `sin(x)=-ax`. Please don't say "you have to actually compute it", since requirements like that are too vague to work.

Comment: Also, `x=0` is a trivial solution. You should specify which solution you want.

Comment: You need some bounds on m to guarantee a nonzero solution.

Comment: `m=0` has solutions (`x=kπ` for integer `k`). The values of `m` which don't have non-trivial real solutions are those which are too far from `0`.

Comment: Are you looking for only real-valued solutions or are complex-valued solutions allowed too?

Comment: I edited the spec with the intent of reopening. If this isn't what you had in mind, please let me know.

Comment: @xnor, are you sure about those test cases? The minimum of `sinc` is about `-0.217`, so I don't think `0.25` is a valid input.

Comment: @PeterTaylor You're right, I had the sign flipped.

Comment: @xnor, IMO it would make more sense to flip the sign and make the question "*Approximate `arcsinc(m)`*" rather than "*Approximate `arcsinc(-m)`*", although that would have been much easier to do in the sandbox than on a posted question with an answer.

Comment: @PeterTaylor I agree it would be cleaner, but that's more functional a change than I'd like to do in editing someone else's question.

Comment: This problem came up yesterday and I solved it naively with python. I was wondering what cool solutions people would come up with. I'm new to the site and don't know how best to pose specific problems – you guys are free to improve the question as you see fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## [ised](http://ised.sourceforge.net/): <s>32</s> 28 bytes

Using Newton's iteration starting from π:

```
{:x-{sinx+$1*x}/{cosx+$1}:}:::pi
```

The argument is passed in `$1`, which can be taken from a file, like this:

```
ised --l inputfile.txt 'code'
```

A bit less stable, but shorter version:

```
{:{x-tanx}/{1+$1/cosx}:}:::pi
```

Sometimes it throws iteration limit warnings but the accuracy seems fine considering the conditions.

Unicode version (same bytecount):

```
{λ{x-tanx}/{1+$1/cosx}}∙π
```

Starting from 4 cuts another byte and seems to converge to the same values

```
{λ{x-tanx}/{1+$1/cosx}}∙4
```

Answer (score 8):

### Haskell, 34 bytes

```python
f m=until(\x->sin x< -m*x)(+1e-3)0
```

Counts `x` up from 0 by 0.001 until `sin(x)< -m*x`.

Ouput examples

```
f -0.2 ->   2.595999999999825
f -0.1 ->   2.852999999999797
f  0.0 ->   3.141999999999765
f  0.1 ->   3.4999999999997256
f  0.2 ->   4.1049999999997056
```

Comment: What about `m=-0.1`?

Comment: @PeterTaylor Note sure if it's required, but it gives `2.853`, which looks right.

Comment: Of course, they're both odd functions so if there's a solution there's a positive solution. Doh.

Comment: Why would you answer a challenge that you know is unclear?

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 28 bytes

```
x/.FindRoot[Sinc@x+#,{x,1}]&
```

Searches for a numerical root from the initial guess `x=1`. Test cases:

```
% /@ {-0.25, -0.1, 0.2}
(* {2.47458, 2.85234, 4.10462} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

## C, 99 bytes

```c
#include<math.h>
float f(float m){float x=1,y;do{x=(y=sin(x)+m*x)+x;}while(fabs(y)>1e-4);return x;}
```

ungolfed:

```c
#include<math.h>
float f(float m){
 float x=1,y;
 do{x=(y=sin(x)+m*x)+x;}while(fabs(y)>1e-4);
 return x;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## C++ 11, <s>92</s> 91 bytes

-1 byte for using `#import`

```c++
#import<cmath>
using F=float;F f(F m,F x=1){F y=sin(x)+m*x;return fabs(y)>1e-4?f(m,x+y):x;}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](http://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 17 bytes

```
`@2e3/tY,wG_*>}4M
```

This uses linear search on the positive real axis, so it is slow. All test cases end within 1 minute in the online compiler.

[Try it online!](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=YEAyZTMvdFksd0dfKj59NE0&input=LTAuMjU)

#### Explanation

```
`         % Do...while
  @       %   Push iteration index, starting at 1
  2e3/    %   Divide by 2000
  t       %   Duplicate
  Y,      %   Sine
  w       %   Swap
  G_*     %   Multiply by minus the input
  >       %   Does the sine exceed that? If so, next iteration
}         % Finally (execute after last iteration, before exiting loop)
   4M     %   Push input of sine function again
          % Implicit end
          % Implicit display
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, <s>81</s> 78 bytes

#### Fixpoint iteration

As recursive lambda

```python
from math import*
f=lambda m,x=1:abs(sin(x)+m*x)>1e-4and f(m,sin(x)+m*x+x)or x
```

As loop (81 bytes):

```python
from math import*
m=input()
x=1
while abs(sin(x)+m*x)>1e-4:x=sin(x)+m*x+x
print x
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 52 bytes

```
NSolve[Sin@x==-x#,x,Reals][[;;,1,2]]~DeleteCases~0.&
```

Anonymous function. Takes a number as input, and returns a list of numbers as output. Just uses `NSolve` to solve the approximate equation.

Comment: If you replace `Sin@x==-x#` with `Sinc@x==-#` you can do away with `~DeleteCases~0.`

Answer (score 0):

## Axiom, 364 bytes

```
bisezione(f,a,b)==(fa:=f(a);fb:=f(b);a>b or fa*fb>0=>"fail";e:=1/(10**(digits()-3));x1:=a;v:=x2:=b;i:=1;y:=f(v);if(abs(y)>e)then repeat(t:=(x2-x1)/2.0;v:=x1+t;y:=f(v);i:=i+1;if i>999 or t<=e or abs(y)<e then break;if fb*y<0 then(x1:=v;fa:=y)else if fa*y<0 then(x2:=v;fb:=y)else break);i>999 or abs(y)>e=>"fail";v)
macro g(m) == bisezione(x+->(sin(x)+m*x), 0.1, 4.3)
```

ungolf

```
bisezione(f,a,b)==
    fa:=f(a);fb:=f(b)
    a>b or fa*fb>0=>"fail"
    e:=1/(10**(digits()-3))
    x1:=a;v:=x2:=b;i:=1;y:=f(v)
    if(abs(y)>e) then
      repeat
        t:=(x2-x1)/2.0;v:=x1+t;y:=f(v);i:=i+1
        if i>999 or t<=e or abs(y)<e then break
        if      fb*y<0 then(x1:=v;fa:=y)
        else if fa*y<0 then(x2:=v;fb:=y)
        else break
    i>999 or abs(y)>e=>"fail"
    v

macro g(m) == bisezione(x+->(sin(x)+m*x), 0.1, 4.3)
```

results

```
(3) -> g(0.2)
   AXIOM will attempt to step through and interpret the code.
   (3)  4.1046198505 579058527
                                                              Type: Float
(4) -> g(-0.1)
   (4)  2.8523418944 500916556
                                                              Type: Float
(5) -> g(-0.25)
   (5)  2.4745767873 698290098
                                                              Type: Float
```

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell, 50 bytes

I just learned about newton's method in my calc class, so here goes in `haskell` using newton's method.

`f m=foldl(\x _->x-(sin x+m*x)/(cos x+m))0[1..10]`

Answer (score 0):

## [Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/), 68 bytes

Modified from [@xnor's Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/97654/110802).

---

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY9BC4JAFITv/op33C1ctG7CCkHXThEdIuKpz9zYXWXdwgh/u4ke9TTMxzDMtDlqHOrsRbmHEyoLvwCgoBLMaBi6Z5vAwTn83s7eKfu88wQuVnmQUxKgGanXlpUsjMSO8yWMFzAS0Qpby82FfRB8UEOZwLF@Z5pkOivIwch0HEZohPLk0NNUzh7bmMI9F4Wrm2ulNLFOpgZ9JdrxVsdTCWG3MVxUhMXQD38)

```scala
m=>Stream.iterate(0.0)(_+1e-3).dropWhile(x=>math.sin(x)>= -x*m).head
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dZBLC8IwEITv/RVzTLQtrd6KCopXT@JJRGJNayRNpI0Qkf72al8KPk7ZzH6Z2U0RM8mqSh/OPDZYMaFwd4AjT5A9L4TlaRFhnufstl2bXKh0RyNslDCYNiRweapGKpIQL/BHlH6L4ZcY@MEP7RfXGpZON1RCsghLfT1ITvviNUkNXJURksRaHYURWr2ZGRZaS86UCxZ/ttrKhf1vDogEb2NiKYXtOlwW/DO5j@nP@kGDN7ugw22dvmLm5BeiRjCBl2EA62KPIULujV0E7ReUTlU9AA)

```scala
object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(f(-0.2))
    println(f(-0.1))
    println(f(0.0))
    println(f(0.1))
    println(f(0.2))
  }

  def f(m: Double): Double = {
    def until(condition: Double => Boolean, action: Double => Double, x: Double): Double = {
      if (condition(x)) x
      else until(condition, action, action(x))
    }

    until(x => Math.sin(x) < -m * x, _ + 1e-3, 0)
  }
}
```